# Node.JS Response Time

Tags: performance, node.js, amazon-web-services

Threw Node.JS on an AWS instance and was testing the request times, got some interesting results.

I used the following for the server:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('Hello World');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I have an average 90ms delay to this server, but the total request takes ~350+ms. Obviously a lot of time is wasted on the box. I made sure the DNS was cached prior to the test.

I did an Apache bench on the server with a cocurrency of 1000 - it finished 10,000 requests in 4.3 seconds... which means an average of 4.3 milliseconds.

**UPDATE: Just for grins, I installed Apache + PHP on the same machine and did a simple "Hello World" echo and got a 92ms response time on average (two over ping).**

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: how did you measure total request time? how did you benchmark 10000 requests time?

Comment: @AndreySidorov Just used Chrome Developer Tools locally for request time, I did an apache bench for the server.

Comment: hey Jonathan, so the conclusion is?... response time with node is slow? would be interesting to investigate further

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Actually, the contrary. See my answer for some more details, but through process of elimination, it seems that calling ``res.write()`` kills performance. So using packages like express.js which don't use that function will help a lot. When done correctly, I was getting a response of 1-2ms over ping with node.js

Comment: Or just use Fastify ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I absolutely hate answering my own questions, but I want to pass along what I have discovered with future readers.

**tl;dr: There is something wrong with res.write(). Use express.js or res.end()**

I just got through conducting a bunch of tests. I setup multiple types of Node server and mixed in things like PHP and Nginx. Here are my findings.

As stated previously, with the snippet I included above, I was loosing around 250ms/request, but the Apache benchmarks did not replicate that issues. I then proceeded to do a PHP test and got results ranging from 2ms - 20ms over ping... a big difference.

This prompted some more research, I started a Nginx server and proxied the node through it, and somehow, that magically changed the response from 250ms to 15ms over ping. I was on par with that PHP script, but that is a really confusing result. Usually additional hops would slow things down.

Intrigued, I made an express.js server as well - and something even more interesting happened, the ping was 2ms over on its own. I dug around in the source for quite a while and noticed that it lacked a `res.write()` command, rather, it went straight to the `res.end()`. I started another server removing the "Hello World" from the `res.write` and added it to the `res.end` and amazingly, the ping was 0ms over ping.

I did some searching on this, wanted to see if it was a well-known issue and came across this SO question, who had the exact same problem. [nodejs response speed and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335510/nodejs-response-speed-and-nginx)

Overall, intresting stuff. Make sure you optimize your responses and send it all at once.

Best of luck to everyone!

Answer (score 15):

While Chrome Developer Tools is a good way to investigate front end performance, it gives you very rough estimate of actual server timings / cpu load. If you have ~350 ms total request time in dev tools, subtract from this number DNS lookup + Connecting + Sending + Receiving, then subtract roundtrip time (90 ms?) and after that you have first estimate. In your case I expect actual request time to be sub-millisecond. Try to run this code on server:

```
var http = require('http');
function hrdiff(t1, t2) {
    var s = t2[0] - t1[0];
    var mms = t2[1] - t1[1];
    return s*1e9 + mms;
}
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var t1 = process.hrtime();
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('Hello World');
  res.end();
  var t2 = process.hrtime();
  console.log(hrdiff(t1, t2));
}).listen(8080);
```

Based on `ab` result you should estimate average send+request+receive time to be at most 4.2 ms ( 4200 ms / 10000 req) (did you run it on server? what concurrency?)

Comment: +1 For an intelligent answer. All very interesting. In my local test, DNS was cached, so without ping, the request took 260ms - according to the snippet your provided, the average request for this is around 0.6 milliseconds. On the ab, I did it on server with concurrency at 1000. **Those numbers make sense, but I'm still at a loss when it comes to that 260ms**

Comment: Further interesting numbers, testing Apache/PHP on the same box, I'm getting a response time of 92ms (two over ping). While i'm still getting roughly 350ms on the NodeJS script. I feel like i'm missing something...

Comment: I have very similar results with Apache/PHP and with node.js when measuring from the client. Can you do more detailed measurements using https://github.com/mnot/htracr or just use tcpdump and post your results?

Comment: I actually figured it out - see my answer. I'll go ahead and award you the bounty for the help, however! Thank you sir.