# node.js response.write(data) taking long time when size of data is small

Tags: node.js

I've noticed a strange behavior of the performance of the following code in node.js. When the size of `content` is 1.4KB, the response time of the request is roughly 16ms. However, when the size of `content` is only 988 bytes, the response time of the request is strangely much longer, roughly **200ms**:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
response.write(JSON.stringify(content, null, 0));
response.end();
```

This does not seem intuitive. Looking into Firebug's net tab, the increase/difference all comes from receiving (waiting on the other hand is 16ms for both).

I've made the following change to fix it so that both cases have 16ms response time:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
response.end(JSON.stringify(content, null, 0));
```

I've looked through node.js [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding) but so far haven't found related info. My guess this is related to the buffering, but could node.js preempt between `write()` and `end()`?

**Update:**

This was tested on v0.10.1 on Linux.

I tried to peek into [source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.1-release/lib/http.js) and have identified the difference between the 2 path. The first version has 2 Socket.write calls.

```
writeHead(...)
write(chunk)
  chunk = Buffer.byteLength(chunk).toString(16) + CRLF + chunk + CRLF;
  ret = this._send(chunk);
    this._writeRaw(chunk);
      this.connection.write(chunk);
end()
  ret = this._send('0\r\n' + this._trailer + '\r\n'); // Last chunk.
    this._writeRaw(chunk);
      this.connection.write(chunk);
```

The second, good version has just 1 Socket.write call:

```
writeHead(...)
end(chunk)
  var l = Buffer.byteLength(chunk).toString(16);
  ret = this.connection.write(this._header + l + CRLF +
                              chunk + '\r\n0\r\n' +
                              this._trailer + '\r\n', encoding);
```

Still not sure what makes the first version not working well with smaller response size.

Comment: A far as I know those should do essentially the same thing and I can't reproduce this locally. Can you try coming up with a full reproducible test case and throw it in a fiddle or gist for us to check out? Are you running all this locally?

Comment: Also, can you clarify your env?  windows? osx? linux?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422411/node-js-response-time

Comment: somewhat related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335510/nodejs-response-speed-and-nginx

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:**

**you can explicitly set the** `Content-Length` **header.** It will reduce to response time from around 200ms to 20ms.

```
var body = JSON.stringify(content, null, 0);
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Content-Length': body.length
});
response.write(content);
response.end();
```

**Facts:**

After a few experiments, I found that **if the** `content` **is small enough (In my case, less than 1310 bytes) for a single [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) to carry on, the response time would be around 200ms**. However, for any `content` larger than that value, the response time would be roughly 20ms.

Then I used wireshark to capture the server side's network packages. Below is a typical result:

For small `content`:

- [0000ms]`response.write(content)`
- [0200ms]received the ACK package from client
- [0201ms]`response.end()`

For larger `content`:

- [0000ms]`response.write(content)` //The first MTU is sent
- [0001ms]the second MTU is sent
- [0070ms]received the ACK package from client
- [0071ms]`response.end()`

**Possible Explanation:**

If `Content-Length` header is not set, the data would be transferred in "Chunked" mode. In "Chunked" mode, neither server nor the client know the exactly length of the data, so the client would wait for while (200ms) to see if there is any following packages.

However, this explanation raise another question: **why in the larger** `content` **case, the client did not wait for 200ms (instead, it waited only around 50ms)?**

Comment: but in chunked transfer encoding, there's a explicit ending signal, so "chunked" can't explain this issue.

Comment: Wait time is proportional to empty bits in the last MTU received, I dont have data to prove but seems logical way to implement logic