# How can I receive a data such as dns lookup time, page load time and other on node js?

Tags: node.js, timing, navigation-timing-api

I want to receive the next data of web page:

- dns lookup time
- page load time (before an event 'onLoad')
- TTFB
- total time (dns lookup time + page load time)

How can I do this on a node js?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't have experience with this myself, but it seems like an interesting question so I looked it up a bit and here's what I found:

- dns lookup time: http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

For all other points you asked I didn't manage to find any direct usage, but as it seems NewRelic does this already so you may want to check them out. On [this link](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/page-load-timing-nodejs) they show the how-to.

As a side note, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335510/nodejs-response-speed-and-nginx) here on StackOverflow if it gets you some help, and this module may be of interest to you too: https://github.com/shunanya/Node.js-monitoring.